# Need a way to check to see if a wildcard string matches a given string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out how to create a function where I can pass in two strings, one with wildcards and another that is checked to see if it matches the wildcard string.

```
$wildcard_string = '*.example.com/some/path/*';
$test_string = 'dev.example.com/some/path/art123.html';

function test_wildcard_match($wildcard_string, $test_string){

  //return true or false

}
```

Comment: Will you always be searching for a complete substrings, i.e. wildcards at both ends ?

Comment: It could be anything that the user could think of. In the middle, at the ends...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)

Comment: Wow, that is great. I am always amazed at the number of built in functions in php.

Answer (score 2):

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php